# Errors occur when used "**constant**" in struts.xml file (strust 2.3.4 framework)

Tags: struts2

I'm trying run project with framework strust2.3.4 but errors occur
when I used "**constant**" in struts.xml file

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.pfs.pnn.action"/>
```

and config action

```
<action name="system_list" class="SystemListAction">
     <result name="success">/pages/system_list.jsp</result>
</action>
```

error :

```
Caused by: Action class [SystemListAction] not found - action - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/pnn/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:8:58
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:434)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:378)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:495)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 16 more
```

I don't know where mistakes.Please help me!

Comment: Hi, try put the whole path to your action definition: `<action name="system_list" class="com.pfs.pnn.action.SystemListAction">`

Comment: If you're using convention why are you also defining the action in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

add struts2convention plugin and not mention complete package 
`<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="action"/>`
for more
link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Convention%20Plugin